# Why does some code not work in a function that's in a process in python?

Tags: python-multiprocessing

In my script, I noticed that some of my code isn't running. For example, in my "count()" function, frames.append(frame) doesn't run. I know it doesn't run because I get an empty MKV file and because my list called "frames" has nothing in it. Besides that not running, if I were to put "if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):" inside the count function it wouldn't execute.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import keyboard
# For other stuff
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import pyaudio
import wave
import moviepy.editor as mpe
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import os
import sys

y = 0
frames = []       
z = 0


# Variables for 'count()'
x = 0
# display screen resolution
SCREEN_SIZE = (1920, 1080)
# define the codec
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
# create the video write object
out = cv.VideoWriter("output.mkv", fourcc, 25.0, (SCREEN_SIZE))

def count():
    print("Count function started!")
    while x == 0:
        # make a screenshot
        img = pyautogui.screenshot()
        frame = np.array(img)
        # convert colors from BGR to RGB
        frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # write the frame
        frames.append(frame)
        print("Frame added!")
        if y == 1:
            break

def increase_var():
    global z
    z += 1
    print(z)
    print(frames[0])

def release_video():
    if y == 1:
        print("Started processing frame data...")
        for i in frames:
            out.write(i)
            print("Loop functioning.")
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        out.release()
        print("Count function proccessed.")

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
        input("Start?")
        print("Both recording")
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
            p1 = ctx.Process(target = count)
            p1.start()
            while True:
                if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                    print("Did it!!!")
                    y += 1
                    print("y = " + str(y))
                    break
            input("Done?")
            increase_var()
            if z == 1:
                x = x + 1
                print("x was increased!")
        
        
    if x == 1:
        p1.terminate()
        p1.join()
        release_video()
        print("We're here!")
        input()
        x += 1
```

Comment: The `frames` in the process that's running `count()` is utterly unrelated to the `frames` you are using in the main process.  You have to use specific types from the `multiprocessing` module if you want variables to be shared between processes.

Comment: you have never called the function count() and if in the sixth line under while loop is the count function that's not how a function is called.  'count' is a keyword in python so change the name to something else.